# Google Analytics API. Problems with two conditions using the metric transactionRevenue in one segment

Tags: api, google-analytics, transactions, revenue

I am using the Google Analytics API to automatically fetch stats from eccomerce sites. I need to query a dynamic segment with the sessions that spent more than 0 and less than 50USD in ecommerce.

I tried this:
`segment=users::condition::perSession::ga:transactionRevenue>0;users::condition::perSession::ga:transactionRevenue<50`

But it looks like the API is ignoring the ga:transactionRevenue < 50 condition, returning all the sessions with ga:transactionRevenue>0. I tried some other metrics in the > 0 condition ( like uniquePurchases , ga:transactionTax...) with the same results.

The fun part is that if I use transactionShipping it works OK ( returning the sessions with purchases including shipping costs and with less than 50USD revenue):
`segment=users::condition::perSession::ga:transactionShipping >0;users::condition::perSession::ga:transactionRevenue<50`

But this is not OK, because I need to include the free shippingtransactions on the segment.

Anybody nows a workarround for this?

Comment: Just did this: created a segment in GA web UI with the 2 conditions, verified that it works. Then looked at the API output of the management list of segments for the account. it says the segment definition is:

Comment: sessions::condition::ga:transactionRevenue>0;ga:transactionRevenue<=50  Then I realized that the API doesn't like redundant sessions::condition:: sections. Give that a try...

Comment: Hi Mike. I tried your suggestion and it worked correctly. Problem solved! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check how you are processing the segment for sending to the API.

The rule is that you should escape a semicolon in a value expression (\;).  I suspect you are escaping the semicolon between the conditions by accident because you encode/escape everything after the 'segment='  like `segment=<encoded/escaped segment definition>`

What you need to to send `segment=<encoded/escaped condition1>;<encoded/escaped condition2>`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Mike, but this is not the case. I am not escaping the semicolons between conditions. In fact I am using other conditions combinations separated with semicolons ( up to 7 conditions ) and they work perfectly.

Comment: Good to know - worth a try.